# Text-decoration:none will not remove link underline, but line-through works fine, why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a piece of code for my website, however can't seem to get rid of the underline on the link. I keep testing it on w3schools and it's not disappearing. The code is as below:

```html
   <p><span style="color: #ff8000; font-size:80%; font-family:roboto">Please <a href="#"><span style="color: #525252; font-size:100%; font-family:roboto;">contact us</a> if you are interested in this product.</p>
```

I can't find an answer to my question anywhere, when I do text-decoration: line-through, it works, so why not text-decoration: none?

Comment: please show us the code you have. and what you have tried

Comment: Your HTML has an unclosed `span` inside the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The css property for removing the underline of `anchor` elements is:

`text-decoration: none`

Maybe you are applying the css style to the wrong element. 
Make sure you apply it to the `<a>` element

```html
   <p><span style="color: #ff8000; font-size:80%; font-family:roboto">Please <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#"><span style="color: #525252; font-size:100%; font-family:roboto;">contact us</a> if you are interested in this product.</p>
```

Comment: @isherwood I updated my answer, It appears that the user maybe is applying the style to the wrong element. As you can clearly see, `text-decoration: none` works just as it's supposed to